# chr for non-ASCII characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to implement a search through a list of strings, in a context where there's no way to use something like `str.startswith` (If you're curious about it, I'm querying the app engine datastore.) I'd like to look for every string that has a certain prefix, let's say 'py'.

I have comparison operators at my disposal, so I was thinking I could implement this as follows.

```
#pseudo code
search = "py"
search_strings_where(s > search, s < chr(ord(search[0]) + 1)
```

The `chr(ord(search[0]) + 1)` is supposed to be the character that's in lexicographical order right after the first character of the search query.

The problem is that this won't work. take for example `ord(u"‰")`, which returns 8240. But putting that into `chr`again raises an error.

```
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

How could I solve this?

EDIT
Just found out about unichr, checking if this works. I will write an answer if it does.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Perhaps use [unichr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr), this function will be worked

Comment: I found out about  unichr while searching a bit further on the web. Thx for your answer.

Comment: @InbarRose The answer actually provides sufficient information without clicking the link.  OP says "I know what `chr` does, what's the equivalent for unicode?"  The one word answer `unichr` would suffice.  Perhaps clarification that it's built in would be useful, but it *is* a complete answer, even if it's short.

Comment: @Jack Necro much? This post is 2 years old, my comment about his answer is before he edited it. What is your point? And what does this add to the answer? Now that my attention is drawn to this, I can delete my previous comment - normally I would assume someone would mark my comment simply as "obsolete" but I guess this works too.